# Call to java script code returning the ASCII encoding for ':' separating key and value of returned object

Tags: karate

I making an api request using karate where one of the api request params takes a filter condition (which is a java script object).

I am using a literal notation to create a java script object as shown below. This code is in a separate filter.js file.

```
function() {

var params = {
    val1:[],
    val2:[]
};
return params;
```

}

Now i call the above .js file in the karate scenario as below:

```
 Scenario: Test
Given path 'filtertest/'
* param filter = call read('classpath:feature/common/filter/filter.js')
When method get
```

Ran the above and when i check the log, the api throws bad request error. I looked at the request url and there i can see that the ':' in the js file where I am assigning a value to a object key is replaced with %3A which i believe is the ASCII encoding for ':'. (the param with its values below)

> ?filter=%7B%22val1%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22val2%22%3A%5B%5D

What I want is the ':' to come as it is from the .js call as the server side expects the filter param values as key value pairs.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server cannot decode an encoded `:` it is a bug: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

If you really need this - the workaround is to use the `url` keyword and build it manually, `path` and `param` will *always* encode.

```
Given url baseUrl + '/filtertest?filter=foo:bar'
```