# Removing quotes from param values in karate request

Tags: karate

**Scenario:** I get response from a karate request which is in the form as below:

```
idValues = ["123:ABCD-F", "345:CFGB-F", "678:DERF-F"]
```

I then need to make a further request in a scenario where the values from array above is passed in karate's request `* param` as below:

```
Given path 'users','details'
* param = 123:ABCD-F, 345:CFGB-F, 678:DERF-F
When method get
Then status 200
```

**Issue:** I need to send this list of ids as comma separated values without the `"` quotes to the param keyword. If the values are passed to params with quotes, karate further encloses the ids within quotes (which is the correct behaviour i think) and because of this i do not get the expected response.

Wanted to know if there is a way to:
1. Take the values out of the array, remove the quotes from start and end.
2. Pass these as comma separated values to `param' keyword (as shown in the example above).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 suggestions.

`karate.forEach()` can do any kind of conversion you want. Here is an example. If you find this too ugly, use Java (search the docs for Java Interop):

```
* def idValues = ["123:ABCD-F", "345:CFGB-F", "678:DERF-F"]
* def fun = function(x, i){ var s = karate.get('temp'); if (i) x = ',' + x; karate.set('temp', s + x) }
* def temp = ''
* karate.forEach(idValues, fun)
* print temp
```

`param` will *always* encode, and as you said - it is the right behavior. So use `url` and manually concatenate the path you need. Refer this answer for more:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55357704/143475